# copy and insert rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

hey guys I've some data in event_name with a community_code = 1 .
now I need to add rows to the same data to the table with community_code = 2. instead of adding each row, is it possible to add all the rows with different community_code. please help me out thank you.
[image: please look into image for reference.]

Comment: Yes his answer works for me go ahead with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert by querying the table and replacing values as needed. For example:

```
insert into community_comms (id, community_id, event_name) 
select id, 2, event_name
from community_comms
where community_id = 1
```